# Use apt.conf to fail a download if it does not come from a particular PPA

Tags: package-management, upgrade, security, ppa

I think I am being hacked. The attacker seems to have slipped in an unwanted package while I was doing apt upgrade.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in the morning and did apt upgrade. Went to work. And when I come back to view Youtube, my mouse started moving on it's own.

Since I was not using the pc the whole day, it must have been something installed during the upgrade.

I have copied an https address from the Ubuntu mirrors page and used it in my sources.list. So package integrity should not be a problem.

So I gather that the attacker has somehow slipped in a file while I was upgrading and Ubuntu swallowed it whole.

Either that, or there is a vulnerability in the Ubuntu default minimal install.

So, I am trying to eliminate possibilities. I understand that apt.conf can accept PPA site certificates. Would that allow it to reject files not sent from a PPA? If so, what would such a apt.conf look like?

Comment: "Since I was not using the pc the whole day, it must have been something installed during the upgrade."  More likely someone is using the same frequency if it is wireless.

Comment: No, I am not using WiFi